# Having trouble making a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to make a bacth file that will make a second bacth file and set the content of it to this:

powershell shutdown /s /f /t 0

The command I am trying to use is
powershell set-content "shutdown.bat" "powershell shutdown /s /f /t 0"

When I run it I get this:

```
Set-Content : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'shutdown'.
At line:1 char:1
+ set-content -Path shutdown.bat -Value powershell shutdown /s /f /t 0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-Content], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetContentCommand
```

Comment: Don't make a script that's the same name as the command you're running.

Comment: Get-Help Set-Content -examples

Comment: Also try `shutdown /?`, because you should not be using `shutdown.exe` without providing the `/D` option. It will most likely `/D P:4:1`, because there isn't a reason code for planned malicious behavior.

Comment: _Also, you shouldn't use a `0` with `/T` and couple that with the `/F` option, unless you're trying to break something!_

Comment: Using a batch file to create another batch file to run PowerShell to run an external command-line tool makes zero sense. You are literally calling cmd.exe 3 times to run commands.

Answer (score 0):

This ...

```
powershell shutdown /s /f /t 0
```

... is not the way to use Powershell to run external command-line tools or other programs. To run external tools, this is a well-documented / talked about a thing...

> [PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)
>
> [Solve Problems with External Command Lines in PowerShell](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/solve-problems-with-external-command-lines-in-powershell)
>
> [Top 5 tips for running external commands in Powershell](https://powershelleverydayfaq.blogspot.com/2012/04/top-5-tips-for-running-external.html)
>
> [Using Windows PowerShell to run old command-line tools (and their
>   weirdest parameters)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2012/03/03/using-windows-powershell-to-run-old-command-line-tools-and-their-weirdest-parameters)
>
> [Execution of external commands in PowerShell done right](https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/execution-of-external-commands-in-powershell-done-right)

... and fairly daily activity.

Proper quoting and argument termination is a requirement when doing what you are after.

So, stuff like this...

```
powershell -ArgumentList '-Command  &{ shutdown /s /f /t 0 }'
```